# To calculate volume of a solid via triple integral in spherical/cylinder coordinates

Tags: integration, spherical-coordinates, multiple-integral

I come across on a task to calculate the volume of the solid bounded by surfaces as below via triple integral.

$x^2+y^2 \le 3z^2$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2 \le 4$
The first surface seems to be the infinite cone.
The second one is a sphere. So it looks that we have to use spherical coordinates to calculate the volume, but how?
Is it possible to use cylinder coordinates as well for the case?

Comment: Sure, cylindrical coordinates are possible as well.

Comment: it seems to me that the calculation in cylindrical coordinates is more simple. I got the volume $2*\frac {8\pi} {3}$, right?

Comment: Yes, it is more simple :)